# Grammar Question

Tags: grammar

I have a question. Which of these two sentences is correct when I want to say that something that I said was wrong?

1)I said something incorrect.

2)I said something incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

Which sentence is correct depends on what you mean.

**Incorrect** is an *adjective*, so version 1 most likely means you said an **incorrect thing** (something impolite or improper in some other way).

**Incorrectly** is an *adverb*, so version 2 means *something* was **said incorrectly** (e. g. with grammatical or some other *mistakes*).

Comment: Version 1 could also mean that the *information* was incorrect, as in "I said something incorrect just now—that quote isn't from Abraham Lincoln, it was actually coined by some random usenet poster in the 1990s." (In fact, I would interpret it this way first, rather than as anything to do with propriety.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Alex and @1006a. It was so helpful. 
I wanted to say that the information I talked about before was wrong; so, I think the first version is appropriate for this purpose.